# Array transpose work with a (10, 1) and not with a (1, 10) array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to send email to multiple addresses, through a array on the .To, was reading the email addresses in range P2:Z2, and the code wasn't working, i changed the range to M1:M10, and the code worked just fine, what the change that i have to make to function in a (1, 10) arrangement?

```
Sub EnvioEmail()

    Range("B4:K34").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Sheets("Aviso").TextBox1.Text & "\" & Sheets("Aviso").Range("P3").Value

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    Dim EmailTo As String

    EmailTo = Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("Aviso").Range("M1:M10").Value), ";")

    With OutMail
        .To = EmailTo 
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Aviso de Cobrança de Aluguel e Encargos " & Sheets("Aviso").Range("P3").Text
        .Body = "Prezados, " & _
        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Segue em anexo o aviso de cobrança." & _
        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Atenciosamente, "
        .Attachments.Add Sheets("Aviso").TextBox1.Text & "\" & Sheets("Aviso").Range("P3").Value & ".pdf"
        .Display
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: with a horizontal array, you would remove the `Application.Transpose`

Comment: @ScottCraner - but `Join` needs a 1D array, not a 2D one... this has been a thread of questions from OP, starting with [this one marked as a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62067304/email-multiple-recipients-using-adresses-in-a-variable).

Comment: Then use two application.tranpose on a  horizontal range: `EmailTo = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Sheets("Aviso").Range("P2:Z2").Value)), ";")` @BigBen

Comment: @ScottCraner I tried without the Application.Transpose but not worked in the horizontal array. There is no cleaner way then use 2 Application.Transpose?

Comment: You can write a loop to do this.